# Is it possible to prevent Cordova's camera plugin from storing image on device?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, camera

I'm creating a hybrid JavaScript mobile app (Android/iOS) where I wish to use Cordova to take a picture with the devices camera. Once a picture is taken, it will be uploaded to a server. It would be preferred if the image is never stored on the device, only in memory before it is approved by the user and uploaded. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just remove the image after you've uploaded it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is required that the images are never stored at any time due to confidentiality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you're using `Camera` and not `Capture`.
Afterwards, when setting up your camera, make sure to set the `CameraOptions`. Here you can specify if you want to save the file localy or not. You do this by setting the camera option: `saveToPhotoAlbum` to false.
[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) you can check how to setup the camera.
[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) you can find how to setup your camera options.

Comment: Good advice but links are out of date